# how to create identical dual discrete y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a sample data frame as below:

```
Month<-c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr")
Value<-c(12,6,13,3)

xy<-data.frame(Month,Value)
ggplot(xy, aes( x=Month,y=Value))+geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.6)+coord_flip()
```

how do I add a secondary y axis "Month" that is identical to the first one?

Thank you.

Comment: don’t use coord_flip - change x and y in the aes, then you can create a y axis in the usual way, see for example this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales

Comment: the downvote is mine - your question is one of the most commonly asked here in this forum and it is not clear as to why none of those threads didn’t help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly different to Park's answer but the same general idea.

```
library(ggplot2)

Month <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr")
Value <- c(12, 6, 13, 3)

xy <- data.frame(Month, Value)

ggplot(xy, aes(x = length(Month):1, y = Value)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", width =
                                                             0.6) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = length(Month):1,
    labels = Month,
    sec.axis = dup_axis(),
    name = "Months"
  ) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: Identical duplicate y-axes]

Answer (score 2):

Your `Month` is discrete and because `scale_x_discrete` do not have secondary axis options, we need to make another dummy variable `mm` that's continuous then recode that variable.

```
xy %>%
  arrange(Month) %>%
  mutate(mm = 1:4) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=mm,y=Value))+geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.6) +
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:4,
                      labels = c("Apr", "Feb", "Jan", "Mar"),
                      sec.axis = dup_axis()) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]